# R plotting means

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this line of code

```
(c(mean(dt$mean), mean(dt1$mean), mean(dt2$mean),mean(dt3$mean),mean(dt4$mean),mean(dt5$mean)))
```

which gives me the following output

```
[1]  6768316  5214644  7782411  8502594 10427635 15794102
```

How can I graph this output using ggplot?

```
Means1<-(c(mean(dt$mean), mean(dt1$mean), mean(dt2$mean),mean(dt3$mean),mean(dt4$mean),mean(dt5$mean)))%>%
  ggplot(Means1,aes(x=season,y=mean,group=1))
```

I tried this hoping it would graph my means but I got back this error

```
Error in `ggplot()`:
! `mapping` should be created with `aes()`.
✖ You've supplied a <numeric> object
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Hi, it's hard to find what when wrong since you're not posting your dataset, especially the entries of `season` and `group`. In addition, ggplot() should be followed by a command to define what type of plot you're doing.

Try this:

ggplot(Means1,aes(x=season,y=mean,) + geom_point(aes(group=1)))

note that both column name `season` and `1` should be included in the data `Means1`

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this kind of dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(season = rep(c(2017,2018,2019), 2),
            means = c(6768316, 5214644, 7782411, 8502594, 10427635, 15794102),
            group = rep(c("A", "B"), 3))
        
ggplot(df, aes(x = season, y = means)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = group))
```

If you give me information about what type of data you have and what plot you are making, I can give better solution

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I am trying to model the means from a data of football transfers each mean represents the average transfer fee for a three year period so the mean 6768316 corresponds to the seasons 00-03 and 15794102 corresponds to the seasons 15-19

Comment: @Cian can you update the question by including a dummy/example dataset that shows how your dataset is structured? It's still not clear what you are trying to group here with the `aes(group=)` command